# geting json inventory id using resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

i cant get and ID from my json api, how can i do that? I am doing like `$scope.info.id` in my delete function but id doesnt work like that.

Here is my delete function

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, $http,  Inventory, $location) {    
    //getting the objects from Inventory
        $scope.info = Inventory.query();

     $scope.deleteInv = function () {
        Inventory.drop({id: $scope.info.id}, function() {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
   });
```

here is my factory

```
app.factory('Inventory', function($resource, $http) {
return $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/inventory/:id', {id: "@id"},
    {
        drop: {
            method: 'DELETE',
            params: {id: "@id"}
        }
             }
     );
 });
```

And here is my api

```
    {
meta: {
limit: 20,
next: null,
offset: 0,
previous: null,
total_count: 3
},
objects: [
{
category: {},
count: 1,
created: "2014-02-28T11:54:02.831409",
description: "dasdasdasdsa",
id: 20,
location: "asd",
name: "adas11",
resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/20",
status: "sad"
},
{
category: {},
count: 1,
created: "2014-02-28T11:54:03.708003",
description: "dasdasdasdsa",
id: 21,
location: "asd",
name: "adas11",
resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/21",
status: "sad"
},
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should call "drop" function. Instead you should call the 'delete' function which you specified in your factory.

```
$scope.deleteInv = function () {
    Inventory.delete({id: $scope.info.id}, function() {
        $location.path('/');
});
```

Comment: sorry i misspelled, i had that `:id` there, its not working . I do think that i have to correctly write this part `Inventory.drop({id: $scope.info.id}`

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work by id, it's deleting all the objects. maybe i have to `$scope.info.objects.id?` or something

Comment: It must have something to do with the REST API implementation. I usually don't like to have meta objects inside the JSON file. Try remove that, and if that doesn't work, does your approuch with info.objects.id work?

Comment: i cant delete them, they came automatically.